# Subscribe push notification onesignal

Tags: onesignal

I want the users subscribe automatic to a web push notifications don't click to button subscribe. When visit the website to see the message not subscribe

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable for security reasons. The user has to opt in to receive push notifications and subscribe to the website. This is not only a things with OneSignal, but with any push notification provider.